# Trend for windows program now : Installation directory predetermined

Tags: installation, directory

I first noticed this when I installed Chrome and subsequently other programs slowly follow suit. That the installer do not allow you to choose installation directory anymore and automatically install into your C: . I really like the power of choice in this area because my C: resource is scarce so I do not want to fill it up with programmes that I do not use very often.

My question is 
1. Why is this a trend? I read around that its to bypass the need for administrative rights..
2. Is there a way to change this without actually tweaking the default installation directory in the registry.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Programs sometimes choose by themselves where to install, with some programs you can move the program root folder wherever you wish, but sometimes this may cause errors.